# XSLT List all elements/attributes names and values without specifying names

Tags: xml, xslt

I know similar questions have been asked and answered quite often, but I have been unable to extend the answers I've seen to address my situation. The requirements and constraints are as follows;

- Must list each element, in order, top down, one per table row

  - Element value to be one the same row as the element name, third column
  - Attribute name/value pairs to be on the same row as the element name, second column

    - When multiple attributes are present, the element name is repeated on a new row for each attribute, along with the attribute name/value pair
- Must output HTML in table format
- Must **NOT** rely on names in xPath

In my real documents, there are optional elements that may or may not be present, and even the element/attribute names may vary. So, any solution that relies on specifying element names in xPath will not work. It must rely entirely on recursion. I believe this should actually be straightforward, given that XSLT is inherently recursive, but I'm apparently missing some fundamental concept.

Here is an example I put together (based on an example found on the web) that I think is a reasonable approximation of the real documents in terms of the variable structure. I kept all the names the same to make it easier to understand.

```
<college>
    <cl:class name="history" xmlns:cl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <student>
            <name>Bob</name>
            <file att2="second Att" name="/abc/kk/final.c">
            <rollno>
                <level3>
                    <level4>22</level4>
                </level3>
            </rollno>
        </file>
        <function>a()</function>
    </student>
</cl:class>
<cl:class name="economics" xmlns:cl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <student>
        <name>Fred</name>
        <file name="/abc/kk/up.h">
            <rollno>23</rollno>
        </file>
        <function>b()</function>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Mike</name>
        <file name="/xyz/up.cpp">
            <rollno>24</rollno>
        </file>
        <function>c()</function>
    </student>
</cl:class>
<class name="math">
    <student>
        <name>Doug</name>
        <file name="/abc/kk/down.h">
            <rollno>25</rollno>
        </file>
        <function>d()</function>
    </student>
</class>
<class name="physics">
    <classlist>
        <student>
            <name>Dave</name>
            <file name="/simple/st.h">
                <rollno>27</rollno>
            </file>
            <function>e()</function>
        </student>
    </classlist>
</class>
</college>
```

I need to turn that into something like this

```
 <html>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td> <b>Element></b></td>
            <td> <b>Attribute></b></td>
            <td> <b>Value></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  class</td>
            <td>  name: history</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  student</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Name</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  Bob</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  file</td>
            <td>  path:/abc/kk/final.c</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  rollno</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  function</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  a()</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  class</td>
            <td>  name: economics</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  student</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Name</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  Fred</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  file</td>
            <td>  path:/abc/kk/up.h</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  rollno</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  function</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  b()</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  student</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Name</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  Mike</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  file</td>
            <td>  path:/xyz/up.cpp</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  rollno</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  function</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  c()</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  class</td>
            <td>  name: math</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  student</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Name</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  Doug</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  file</td>
            <td>  path:/abc/kk/down.h</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  rollno</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  function</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  d()</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  class</td>
            <td>  name: physics</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  class list</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  student</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  Name</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  Dave</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  file</td>
            <td>  path:/simple/st.h</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  rollno</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>  function</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  e()</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

My current attempt at transforming this looks like this. It actually comes *fairly* close to doing what I need, but it lists all the classes first, and lists some values in the wrong places. It probably also has leftover bits of failed attempts that are no longer needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Element</th>
                <th>Attribute</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()"/>

    <xsl:template match="//*">
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                </td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./@*"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="values"/>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="values" match="*">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="*[position()]"/>
            </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="local-name(parent::*)"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ': ', ., ' ')"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ': ', ., ' ')"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Bonus points if you can help me understand the concept I'm missing.

Comment: I don't understand your expected output: why isn't `college` the first element listed in the table?

Comment: And the XML is not well-formed: `<class list>` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Would this be the correct result of processing your input example (after correcting `class list` to `classlist`): http://imgur.com/a/5KH6w ?

Comment: College wasn't in the output because it's the root and I don't need it. But, it can be included, if it's easier. Yes, I missed that space I accidentally put in classlist. And, not quite, but almost.

Comment: Seriously, stop vandalizing this post.

Answer (score 4):

To list all elements and attributes (and their values) in the given XML, in document order, using the native XSLT recursive processing model, is fairly trivial:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Element</th>
            <th>Attribute</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        </td>
        <td/>
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name(..)"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, I thought it should be trivial. That's close, but it duplicates some rows, such as having two "class" rows for each class; one with, and one without, the attribute. It's also a different approach to displaying the attributes, but that's minor.

Comment: No, it is displaying one row for class and one row for each attribute of class (with the parent element also listed). That is how I understood your requirement, looking at the output you provided. If you want something else, then please clarify.

Comment: Also, this is outputting XML. If you change the output method to html, it no longer works.

Comment: I don't see any *significant* changes. I believe you now have the fundamental approach and should be able to make any required adjustments by yourself.

Comment: I repeat, it doesn't work if you output to html, which is a requirement. I don't know why, which means I don't know how to make it work. So, what you've offered is of no use to me.

Comment: You don't know how to change the output method to html and add an html wrapper around the table?!  Allow me to remind you that this is not a coding service, and you are expected to have at least the most basic understanding of the subject before asking here.